# How to execute an API PUT method that has [[FromForm]] argument in powershell

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, powershell, asp.net-core

My API has a PUT method that update a reservation object.

```
[HttpPut]
public Reservation Put([FromForm] Reservation res) => 
repository.UpdateReservation(res);
```

**I just want to know how can i execute this method in powershell using package manager console in Visual studio?**

Note that this method has [FromForm] model binding method. So I have to send the Reservation data in form data.

I know that if this method had [FromBody] attribute instead of [FromForm] then I can do the following command on powershell.

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation -Method PUT 
-Body (@{Id="5"; Name="Mary"; StartLocation="Tokyo"; EndLocation="Abu Dhabi"} | 
ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

But i want to know what will be the command for [FromForm] attribute, please help?

Comment: try `-ContentType 'multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FromForm attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type `application/x-www-url-formencoded`.
Therefore, set the contentType to `application/x-www-url-formencoded`.

Try it like this

```
$url = "http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation";
$body = @{Id="5"; Name="Mary"; StartLocation="Tokyo"; EndLocation="Abu Dhabi"};
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ClipsURL -Body $body -Method Put -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```